# Capture audio going to speakers

Tags: java, macos, audio, javasound

I know that this has been asked before but I have not yet found an answer. I want to write a Java program on my mac that capture the output in the built in speakers. Is that possible using only Java? If so, how do I do it?

If not possible only using Java, is there a library I can integrate in my code to capture the sound? I read about jack audio, but I cant find an example on how to integrate it to Java and how to capture the sound from the speakers. Has anyone got a tutorial or similar on how to use Jack?

Comment: An EG: http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioRecorder.java.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried that code but it only records the mic on my mac. I would like to capture the audio thats playing on my built in speaker

Comment: Try the 'big bro'  http://www.jsresources.org/examples/AudioRecorder.html

Comment: Tried it, same result. It seems as the mic is the only available input ?